# html form values to a javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

how to insert values in a html table, an array multidimensional in javascript.

Additionally, such as performing calculations between the columns of the array and insert the results into a column of the same array.

thanks for your answers.

Comment: Are you talking about adding two arrays? As in `c[i] = a[i] + b[i];`?

Comment: I can't make enough sense of this question to edit it into something more comprehensible... did you use a translator for this?  Of course, that's not a problem but it might be a good idea to give it another go.

Comment: multimencional, did you mean multidimensional? How to insert values from an html table into a multidimensional array in javascript?

Comment: I'm sorry. You did not phrase your question in the form of a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript code:

```
var multiArray;
window.onload = function() {
    // load the table into the multidimensional array.
    multiArray = [];
    var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('TR');
    for(var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
        var arr = [];
        var tds = trs[i].childNodes;
        for(var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
            var td = tds[j];
            if (td.tagName === 'TD') {
                arr.push(td.innerHTML);
            }
        }
        multiArray.push(arr);
    }
    // perform some calculations between the columns of the array
    var resCalc = [];
    for(i = 0; i < multiArray.length; i++) {
        resCalc[i] = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < multiArray[i].length; j++) {
            resCalc[i] += multiArray[i][j];
        }
    }
    // insert the results into a column of the same array
    var columnToModify = 0; // the index of the column you want to change
    for(i = 0; i < multiArray.length; i++) {
        multiArray[i][columnToModify] = resCalc[i];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

something on Google…

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/3/10003047/html-table-in-to-an-array.aspx